# Action Method Param is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I can't figure out why when it hits my action method, carFileName is null.  I debugged the view and when I iterate through that foreach loop, there is indeed different values in each iteration of that loop for carContent.CarFileName.  So for each button when submitted, it should submit the carFileName associated with that particular button.

```
@if (Model.CarFiles != null && Model.CarnFiles.Count > 0)
{
    @foreach (CarContent carContent in Model.CarFiles)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("GetfileDownloadUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new { carId = Model.CarId, userId = Model.UserId, @carFileName = carContent.CarFileName }))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId);
            @Html.Hidden("carId", Model.CarId);
            @Html.Hidden("carFileName", carContent.CarFileName);        
            <p><input type="submit" name="SubmitCommand" value="download" /> @carContent.Name</p>
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my action method signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetFilDownloadUrl(string carFileUrl, int carId, int userId)
{
           ...
}
```

Here's the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("CarDownloadFile", "Cars/{carId}/{userId}/{carFileName}", new { controller = "Car", action = "GetFileDownloadUrl", carnId = UrlParameter.Optional, userId = UrlParameter.Optional, carFileName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: I see `carnId` in your `MapRoute`, shouldn't it be `carId`? Also I see `carFileName` (MapRoute) vs `carFileUrl` (Controller).

Answer (score 0):

Could be because in your route you refer to `carFileName`, but your action method takes `carFileUrl` and you `carId` in your RouteValueDictionary is spelt `carnId`

Comment: does the names going from your action method param, to your route param to the property in the anonymous method defined in the Form all have to be exactly the same?  And what about ordering?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure they have to be the same name, it's probably good practice that you keep it that way unless you ever need to change the parameter you can easily locate it's usages. Ordering definitely has to be the same.